# RestSharp examples don't work in latest version

Tags: web-services, rest, restsharp

I'm trying to use RestSharp for the first time, but none of the examples I have found work with the current version. For example, the Getting Started example results in the following error:

> `'RestSharp.RestClient'` does not contain a definition for `'Execute'` and no extension method `'Execute'` accepting a first argument of type `'RestSharp.RestClient'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know where I can find working examples using RestSharp 103.x?

Answer (score 0):

According to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/152) `Execute` method is not available on some platforms. You may have to use different RestSharp DLL or use `ExecuteAsync` method instead.